# How to get data from HBase using Spark SQL?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is there any way to create DataFrame using base read without writing any RDD code, just pass some reqiured stuffs like HBase catalog and get dataframe.

I got some suggestion like use SHC (Spark HBase Connector), but I didn't get it.

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I have done with this.
**[Spark Hbase Connector](https://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-connector-a-year-in-review/)** is the way to get data from Hbase using sparksql.